# How can I redirect only my homepage to a different URL on a different server?

Tags: redirect, html, indexing

I am trying to redirect my company's home page (let's call it `example.com`) to a new webpage I built : `example.net`, without losing any archive and sub pages, i.e when a user navigates to `example.com` it will redirect to `example.net`, but when they click on "about us" I want it to go back to `example.com/aboutus`.

I can get it to redirect but every time a user clicks on a link (such as about us) the browser will try to load `example.net/aboutus` rather than `example.com/aboutus`, which does not exist.

I have tried many different redirect commands, 301 commands, .htaccess as well as adding redirects to the index page. Everytime I get the homepage to open to the new URL

I have attached my index page code.

```
<?php 
/**
 * Copyright 2013 
 * @author 
 */ 


include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/example.php");


//print_r($_SERVER);

$pageArr = explode("/", $_GET["q"]);

$_GET["q"] = $pageArr[0];

if($pageArr[1]){
    $_GET["z"] = $pageArr[1];
}

if(!$_GET["q"]){
    $_GET["q"] = "home";
}

$mDevice = null;

if($_GET["print"] == "true"){
    $mDevice = "standard";
}

//Begin defining the main page
$WebPage = new xyWebpage($_GET["q"], $mDevice);
//$WebPage->setCharset("ISO-8859-1");
showPage();


function getPageName(){
    return $_GET["q"];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP guy, but depending on your platform you can use either:

MOD_REWRITE Module for Apache  or IIS re-write module.

Both of these support re-writing URL's which can match your use case.

I'm curious why you would just not replace your home page that you are redirected from on the same server(s), but in any case, since you already have the redirect working you only need it on the .net server.  You will need two rules, one to stop processing if it's a root URL request, and then one for all other requests that will re-write the root back to your .com address. You need that first rule so you don't create a loop between your servers.